# Creating a Gaussian with a cutoff point

Tags: python, gaussian

I am working on creating a Gaussian image with a cutoff point at e^(-2) but i keep running into errors.
I have defined my Gaussian and i am trying to make it so that it has a Boolean return but it is not working.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.misc


sizex=684
sizey=608

X = np.linspace(-sizex/2,sizex/2,sizex)
Y = np.linspace(-sizey/2,sizey/2,sizey)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(X, Y, sparse=True)

def Gauss(xx,yy,centx,centy,sig):

    return 1/np.exp(((xx-centx)**2+(yy-centy)**2)/sig**2) > 1/np.exp(2)

t=Gauss(xx,yy,0,0,100)

scipy.misc.imsave('e6.bmp',t)
```

I keep getting the following error:
TypeError: numpy boolean subtract, the `-` operator, is deprecated, use the bitwise_xor, the `^` operator, or the logical_xor function instead.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
return 1/np.exp(((xx-centx)**2+(yy-centy)**2)/sig**2) > 1/np.exp(2)
```

Returns 1 (true) whwenever the above inequality holds, and 0 otherwise.

If you instead want to set these values to 0, you should use assignment:

```
result = 1/np.exp(((xx-centx)**2+(yy-centy)**2)/sig**2)
result[result <= 1/np.exp(2)] = 0
return result
```

Comment: Thank you, i knew i was doing something wrong.
works great now

Answer (score 0):

It appears that scipy.misc.imsave() does not work with booleans. You can convert your boolean data to integers like this:

```
scipy.misc.imsave('e6.bmp',t.astype(int))
```

Comment: Thank you this was true and i tried it but then it gave a binary image instead of the Gaussian i wanted, i've got it now.
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Well, the function Gaussian() that you defined is boolean - so you can have only two possible values (either the gaussian is below the threshold or above it). I thought this was the result you wanted. If you need something else, please try to explain what it is.